# How to rotate an image in gs

Tags: images, ghostscript

How can I rotate an image with ghostscript? 
I am visualizing eps to screen.
I am using the command:

```
gs image.eps
```

Comment: You might want to give [pdfjam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18373572/562769) from texlive a try as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
gs -dEPSCrop -c "<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice" -f input.eps -c quit
```

P.S this code snippet come from [this post](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-postscript/130548-ghostscript-rotation-output.html) in the rhinocerus forum.

Comment: I have never understood what is '-c quit' for

Comment: @simona, "-c" executes a postscript command. The last "-c" option in the example executes "quit" command and ends the postscript elaboration. If you omit it, you'll obtain a ghostscript prompt waiting for a command.

Answer (score 1):

### A bit more modern Ghostscript

Newer Ghostscript versions come with the much improved `eps2write` device.

```bsh
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=eps2write \
  -sOutputFile=output.eps \
  -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice" \
  -f input.eps
```

The `-dSAFER` option keeps thing safe, prohibiting the input Ghostscript from performing arbitrary file read/write operations.